# Generic, Union and extending. Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have a class `RawTemplate`

```
export type TestUnion = 'test1' | 'test2';
export class RawTemplate {
  someProperty: Record<TestUnion, Record<string, string>>;
}
```

and I create new class `Raw` that extends `RawTemplate`

```
export class Raw extends RawTemplate {
  someProperty: {
    test1: { name1: 'name'; name2: 'name' };
    test2: { name3: 'name' };
  };
}
```

then I create generic a type `Generic` and a type `Target`

```
export type Key<T extends RawTemplate> = keyof T['someProperty'][TestUnion];

export type Generic<T extends RawTemplate> = Record<Key<T>, string>;

export type Target = Generic<Raw>;
```

I want to get the `Target` type like that: `{ name1: string; name2: string; name3: string }` but I get the
follow type: `{}`

If I rewrite my types like that:

```
export type Key<T extends RawTemplate> = keyof T['someProperty']['test1'];

export type Generic<T extends RawTemplate> = Record<Key<T>, string>;

export type Target = Generic<Raw>;
```

I get the follow `Target` type: `{ name1: string; name2: string }` almost as I want.

Or I can rewrite my types like that:

```
export type Key<T extends RawTemplate> = keyof T['someProperty']['test1' | 'test2'];

export type Generic<T extends RawTemplate> = Record<Key<T>, string>;

export type Target = Generic<Raw>;
```

but I get the follow `Target` type again: `{}`

The only working case I found:

```
export type Key1<T extends RawTemplate> = keyof T['someProperty']['test1'];

export type Key2<T extends RawTemplate> = keyof T['someProperty']['test2'];

export type Generic<T extends RawTemplate> = Record<Key1<T>, string> | Record<Key2<T>, string>;

export type Target = Generic<Raw>;
```

How can I to correct write the types? I will to scale the `TestUnion` type and I don't want to rewrite my `Generic` type every time.

Comment: "Advanced" typing isn't a good thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get the property type of a object using tuples (`|`).

```js
// type Target = never
type Target = keyof Raw['someProperty']['test1' | 'test2']
```

You will have to tuple the keys instead.

```js
export type Generic<T extends RawTemplate> = Record<Key<T, 'test1'> | Key<T, 'test2'>, string>;

// type Target = {
//     name1: string;
//     name2: string;
//     name3: string;
// }
export type Target = Generic<Raw>;
```

Or, join the objects and use `keyof` on the that.

```js
// type Target = {
//     name1: string;
//     name2: string;
//     name3: string;
// }
export type Target = { [key in keyof (Raw['someProperty']['test1'] & Raw['someProperty']['test2'])]: string };
```